# Angular 7, recursive object table rows

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-template

Assume we have the following class:

```
export class MyClass {
    field1: string,
    next: MyClass
}
```

I have a table printing a list of `MyClass` but inside each item, there can be a `next` value.

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of _myclasses">
     <ng-template #recursive let-current>
         <td>{{cur.field1}}</td>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursive; context {$implicit: c}"></ng-container>

</tr>
```

But im kind of stuck here cause i need to create another `tr` or some row but I cannot figure how..

Thanks.

Output Example:

```
 let classes = [];

let class1 = new MyClass();
class1.field1 = 1;
class1.next = new MyClass();
class1.next.field1 = 5;

let class2 = new MyClass();
class2.field1 = 3;

classes.push(class1);



<tr>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? Also an example of _myclasses

Comment: @Vega added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you need, you can use nested `ng-container`s.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let c of _myclasses">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursive; context {$implicit: c}"></ng-container>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-template #recursive let-current>
     <tr>
        <td>{{cur.field1}}</td>
     </tr>
    <ng-container *ngIf="cur.next">
         <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursive; context {$implicit: cur.next}"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
 </ng-template>
```

---

Or maybe you can create a `pipe` that takes `_myclasses` and `flatten` it recursively and returns a one-level array of objects.

Comment: Glad to help :) But I suggest you to search for solutions about flattening the array via a pipe. It will be a lot cleaner that way.

Comment: I dont want to flat the array. because i want to keep the references objects have to each other. in my project is far more complex than this example :)

Comment: No I mean using `pipes`. They do not mutate your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

You did almost right, just a little correction:

```
 <ng-template #recursive let-cur="current">
     <ng-template [ngIf]="cur">
         <tr>
             <td>{{cur.field1}}</td>
         </tr>
         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="recursive"
             [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ current: cur.next }">
         </ng-container>
     </ng-template
 </ng-template>

<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="_myclasses">
     <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="recursive"
         [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ current: item }">
     </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

But for may taste this looks weird and too complex. May be its better to just unroll that recursive class to a flat array before rendering?